# How to change font size of a label when a new string replaces the old

Tags: python, string, label, size, kivy

For example, let's say this new string in my .py file replaces the old one in my .kv file `self.fe.text = finalstr`.  How would I change the font/text size of this new string in the label?

Comment: You want to make a label's text font smaller if the text is too long, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.fe.font_size = '20sp'
```

https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html

You can always look at official documentation for more info